# Scroll element horizontally every time a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble figuring out how to scroll an element by 100px every time a button is clicked at the moment:

```
$('.horizontal-scroll').on('click', '.horizontal-scroll-indicator', function() {
        $(this)
        .prev('.actionbar-inner')
        .animate({scrollLeft: +100});
     });
```

my logic only scrolls it 100px from the left at any given time, where as I want to scroll it by 100px every time a button is clicked, not depending on where current scroll is positioned, so even if it is in the middle, still only scroll it 100px to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to autoincrement with the `+=` operator:

```
$('.horizontal-scroll').on('click', '.horizontal-scroll-indicator', function() {
    $(this)
    .prev('.actionbar-inner')
    .animate({scrollLeft: '+=100'});
 });
```